# What effect does k have on accuracy in k-fold cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation

So, I tried implementing k-fold cross validation with different ks. When k was equal to 3 resulting accuracy was 95 and 97 for k=1 and 7. I realise that there are other factors involved when predicting accuracy. But what effect does k have on it? And moreover why is it larger for k=1 than for k=3?

Answer (score 1):

Most software packages would not allow you to select $k=1$ because at that point, there is a fundamental conceptual difference to $k\geq 2$.

With $k=1$, you are measuring training-set performance which is not an adequate way to assess your model's prediction performance. You will be prone to over-fitting which would manifest itself in overly optimistic training-set performance.

Now those changes from 0.95 to 0.97 are not that huge, they may not mean much.